# How to check DB hours and Minutes lesser than current Hours and minutes in php?

Tags: php

I want to check DB Hours Minutes Lesser than equal to Current time and hours,

For example,

In Db , $from_time = 12.00Am, $current_time = 8.10 Am in these case user can't go to shop,Because fromtime is 12.00Am.

$from_time = 12.00Am, $current_time = 12.10 Am in these case user can go to shop,Because fromtime is 12.00Am,User can do anything after that current hours greater than equal to my db details.

$to_time = 9.00pm $current_time = 8.20 in these case user can't go to shop. how to check like these in php?

Comment: How are you storing the dates in the db? What have you tried? If you google `time comparison mysql` you'll get lots of suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$from_time = strtotime($from_time_from_DB);
$to_time = strtotime($to_time_from_DB);
$current_time = strtotime("now");

if(   $current_time >= $from_time 
   && $current_time < $to_time   ) 
{ 
    //user can go to shop
}
else
{
    //user can't go to shop
}
```

Comment: Probably should be `>=` and `<=`

Comment: @darren-sweeney only in `$current_time >= $from_time`  maybe? at the last minute before the close of the user should not go to shop